# How is closeness between siblings in a tree represented?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

E.g. one might want to say "whale" is a "child" of animal but "whale" is more like "dolphin" than "dog". "whale", "dolphin", "dog" are all children of animal in this case but "whale" and "dolphin" clearly have a relationship.

I AM NOT interested in simply defining more sub-classes (for example "sea animals", "land animals") the above example is just for illustration...assume we can't "define" our way out of the problem.

Does one simply just define a weighted part-acyclic graph with the knowledge that some subset of that graph is really a tree (not necessarily spanning)?

EDIT: A number of people have asked for more clarification. I'll use the same example but probably go into more detail

Say we have the following categories:

```
    Animals, Place, Object.
    The following sub categories: [land animals, sea animals], [country, state],
 [heavy object, light object]
    And we have the following entries: Whale, Dolphin, Dog, Cat, Hawaii, Japan,
 London, Stone, Rock, Leaf, Car.

    I have an isLike(entry x) function that I can call on any of the entries.

    for example say whale.isLike(dolphin) = 0.7, whale.isLike(dog) = 0.2 and
a table like the following one stores all the values for the isLike() function

            Whale dolphin dog cat hawaii japan london stone
    whale   1     0.7     0.2 0.2  0.01   0.01  0.01   0.008
    dolphin 0.7   1       0.2 0.2  0.01   0.01  0.01   0.008
    dog      etc
    cat      etc
    hawaii    etc 
    japan    etc
    london   etc
    stone    etc
```

What is the best way to represent this data?

I am most concerned about how to keep the hierarchical information (tree) as well as the relationship information in isLike() (weighted graph)

so just asking if the standard thing to do is to use a directed graph (for the tree) + weighted undirected graph (for relations) type of structure? Is this standard or is there a more standard way?

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you are trying to represent and why. There are countless ways to compare animals. Some relations can be expressed numerically (like swimming speed), other may be better represented with graphs. What is your input data? Also, what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a weighted, undirected edge to represent closeness in the graph. It's not clear, though, what you are trying to accomplish here. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may want to separate the relationships from the classification hierarchy.

Comment: Michael I have edited the question to provide more clarity...what do you think now?..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of ways to define distance between nodes in a tree. You can use parents, siblings, uncles, etc. To learn more, check out [Red-Black Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

Your stipulation of definition doesn't make sense. The only way that we can define distance is by adding some structural information to the tree such that we know how to arrange the nodes. That's what "sub-classes" do in a hierarchical relationship. The links are essentially just "edges", as any [tree can be transformed into a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Definition_in_graph_theory).

If your nodes are just labels, then they are [nominal pieces](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/presenting_data.html#nomdatvv) of data. There's no way that you can calculate any ratios or intervals, so any distance metric would have to be equal to the number of links from the desired node.

If your nodes in the tree correspond to data structures (for example, Animals), then we can assume that each of those structures have shared attributes. (for example: eye color, weight, height, isFurry, etc) These attributes may have domain and range in interval or ratio scales, in which case we can compute a meaningful distance.

To represent the distance between objects here, you can realize that what you are really doing is defining a coordinate space across a set of variables (x= eye color, y=weight, z=height, isFurry=q). So each individual node is actually a vector in the coordinate space defined by the set of common attributes. Consequently, you can calculate a Euclidean distance, Mahabolis Distance, Manhattan Distance, Cosine Similarity, or any other distance metric you want.

Comment: definition means not using a similarity measure but instead grouping things together some more...what i said makes sense...

Comment: But in order to use a similarity measure, we have to have a way of comparing the similarity. Grouping creates associations and structure which we leverage when defining a similarity metric. The way you group implicitly creates distance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do is [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Hierarchical_clustering), and what you have is called distance matrix.

Comment: This seems more applicable to situations where one is trying to find a pattern in the data as opposed to where one already knows the pattern and is just trying to represent it....

Comment: What you already have is the matrix. If you are satisfied with it, the matrix is the answer. But I though you wanted some tree-like structure and you didn't have that structure yet. Hierarchical clustering, and its resulting tree structure (simple grouping of the elements) is what that is.

Comment: based upon the edits made to the question and the example provided (which does define a distance matrix), that sounds like exactly what's going on here. I'm not sure the op understands what he's going for. If you _know_ the hierarchical relationships a priori, then you already have the distances and you can store the links between each node and other nodes. So yes, you store everything in a graph. If you want to use that information to classify a new node, you can use K-Nearest Neighbors. If you don't know the hierarchical relationships, you can discover them with HAC.